# Changing the Customised Field Length

Tags: acumatica

I have customised field(String Type) in use and now want to increase its length. I increased the length in the Data Access and also Project XML section and published it.On entering the Value according the new length i am getting error "String or binary data would be truncated. The Statement has been turminated". Below is the Project XML where i am trying to increase the length from 12 to 15

```
    `<PXGridLevel DataMember="AccountRecords" ParentId="phL_grid_Levels#0" 
      TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridLevel">
        <Children Key="Columns">
            <AddItem>
                <PXGridColumn TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridColumn">
                    <Prop Key="DataField" Value="UsrBRXAccountID" />
                    <Prop Key="Width" Value="170" />
                </PXGridColumn>
            </AddItem>
            <PXGridColumn DataField="AccountClassID" OriginalIndex="2" />
        </Children>
    </PXGridLevel>
    </Page>
    <Table TableName="Account">
    <Column TableName="Account" ColumnName="UsrBRXAccountID" 
    ColumnType="string" AllowNull="True" MaxLength="15" DecimalPrecision="2" 
     DecimalLength="15" IsNewColumn="True" IsUnicode="True" />
    </Table>
    <DAC type="PX.Objects.GL.Account">
    <Field FieldName="UsrBRXAccountID" TypeName="string" MapDbTable="Account" 
      TextAttributes="#CDATA" StorageName="AddColumn">
        <CDATA name="TextAttributes"><![CDATA[[PXDBString(15)]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName="BRX Account ID")]]]></CDATA>
      </Field>
      </DAC>
      </Customization> `
```

Comment: Did the length change propagate to the database when you published? You can check UsrBRXAccountID field length with a database management utility like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio if you have direct access to the database.

Comment: I just went through the scenario and works fine for increasing the field size. I can enter values no problem. My guess like HB_Acumatica mentioned is the DB size change didn't make it to the DB. Make sure you do not have other companies in your test site with the same customization with the old size.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. No the size change didnt propagate to the database as it data type is still showing "nvarchar(12)". how to fix it please?

Comment: Retesting what I put together it appears you are correct it is not changing the Database for some reason. (Version 6.10.1511 - MySql). My only recommendation is changing the existing column name in the DB, then reset the site and publish. Then transfer the data. This seems like an issue with Acumatica as it doesn't see the size change. It also didn't work when I unpublished and republished.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to access the DB, your best option is to change the length of the field directly. Just make sure you update your project to use the new length.

If you don't have access to the DB and it works for you, the easiest choice is to create a new Usr field (different name) with the required length. This is because Acumatica applies table customizations defined in the project but ignores any changes to user fields if they already exist, these are fields that start with "Usr".

Another alternative is to write a temporary customization project that contains the SQL query to update the table field for you. Note that this is not officially recommended, so be careful and test it in a non productive environment first, but it is useful in some cases. Here is the XML of such a project, you can use it directly if you enter your Acumatica version in the Customization element:

```xml
<Customization level="500" description="Changes Usr field length"
  product-version="YOURACUMATICAVERSIONHERE">
    <Sql TableName="Account" CustomScript="ALTER TABLE [Account] 
        ALTER COLUMN [UsrBRXAccountID ] nvarchar(15);" />
</Customization>
```

Just publish it once to alter the table and you can remove it later.